# Fallout 4 Mods disable on launch

Tags: fallout-4

The newest fallout 4 update 1.5.157 added mod support.
I have an issue where everytime i open the game i have to go into the mods menu and reenable my mods every single time. I have 135 esps and esms, so you can see the issue i have. Is it supposed to be like this or is it not working properly?

Edit: The issue is not the plugins in the mod manager, its in the game.
[image]

The mods always start disabled, and i don't know if they should stay enabled.
I am also using F4SE so if i start the game through the launcher some of the mods won't function.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. The plugins all get disabled when you start the fallout launcher, not when the game starts. Here is a workaround to save time:

1. Start the fallout launcher (Don't start the game)
2. Re-Enable all the mod plugins using nexus mod manager (plugins tab)
3. Start the game

Nexus manager enables all the mods in one button which is much easier than the in-game manager.